# Who automatically writes vim registers?

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I am playing with vim registers. Opening vim with

```
`vim -i NONE`
```

I can open vim without any register. Then I run ":NERDTree" command. After this operation, I can see these registers:

[image]

Now my question is. Why registers `h` and `o` exists? What exactly is stored in registers?

Comment: Nerdtree is likely to use them internally and then restore them to what they were (empty) without restoring them up to the non existing state. Only recent versions of vim permits us this. Beside this is not important

Answer (score 1):

You need to know how to play:

```
-i {viminfo}    The file "viminfo" is used instead of the default viminfo
                file.  If the name "NONE" is used (all uppercase), no viminfo
                file is read or written, even if 'viminfo' is set or when
                ":rv" or ":wv" are used.  See also |viminfo-file|. 
                {not in Vi}
```

This has no relation with registers. Instead, the vim session will not use the `viminfo` to store marks or to preserve history of commands.

Concerning registers `o` and `h` you will get the answer in `:help quote_alpha`:

```
4. Named registers "a to "z or "A to "Z                 *quote_alpha* *quotea*
Vim fills these registers only when you say so.  Specify them as lowercase 
letters to replace their previous contents or as uppercase letters to append
to their previous contents.  When the '>' flag is present in 'cpoptions' then
a line break is inserted before the appended text
```

Comment: This *has* some relation with `viminfo`: it stores the content of all registers.

Comment: why downvoting something which is right ? Poor people !

Comment: sorry if i'm wrong (please read again my last comment), and sorry to be part of the "poor people", but it looks like your answer does not give any useful info about the OP's question. I just wanted to be helpful to other people. Free to other "good people" to upvote your A.

Comment: read my answer carefully and you will understand what does `vim -i NONE`

Answer (score 1):

This has just been fixed. Grab the [latest nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/commit/e671e403dd1ec1da59f70605c73aaedb6cb0e637) and your woes will magically disappear.